# useEffect cleanup when triggered by state

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I have a component that I trigger via a state object:

```
const Alerts = () => {
  const alert = useStore((state) => state.alert);
  const setAlert = useStore((state) => state.setAlert);

  const alertsModalRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("TRIGGER");
    if (alert) {
      alertsModalRef.current?.present();
    }
  }, [alert]);
  ...
```

I trigger it with a button click from another component on different screens. For example:

```
export function UpdateSomething() {
  const setAlert = useStore((state) => state.setAlert);
  return (
    <View>
      <Button
        title="Continue"
        onPress={() => {
          setAlert("something");
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

When I load my app and hit a triggering button, I see "TRIGGER" is printed once to the console. However, when I go to another screen and hit another button or even when I then go back to the first screen and hit the same button again, it then prints "TRIGGER" three times.

I suspect that I need to add some kind of cleanup method to the `useEffect` - but if so, what is the cleanup required there?
And if it's not that? what is going on?

Sorry, I realize this may have been asked in various forms a million times before. I read the docs and many posts, but still confused.

## Update 1

As Drew recommended, I tested and saw the `Alerts` component is re-mounted whenever I visit a screen in my app, which is using React Navigation.
I also wrap each screen with the following Provider:

## Navigator

```
const WrappedSearchScreen = withModalProvider(SearchScreen);

function SearchNavigator() {
  const SearchStack = createStackNavigator();
  return (
    <SearchStack.Navigator>
      <SearchStack.Screen
        name="Search"
        component={WrappedSearchScreen}
      />
      ...
    </SearchStack.Navigator>
  );
}
```

## Provider

```
...
import { Alerts } from "./Alerts";
import { useStore } from "./store";

export const withModalProvider = (Component: FC) => () => {
  const progressBarVisible = useStore((state) => state.progressBarVisible);
  return (
    <BottomSheetModalProvider>
      <Component />
      <Alerts />
      <ProgressBar
        indeterminate
        color="green"
        visible={progressBarVisible}
        style={{ position: "absolute", bottom: 0, left: 0 }}
      />
    </BottomSheetModalProvider>
  );
};
```

Comment: Well, the effect will run at least once when the component mounts, and with `useStore` hook I suspect you are subscribed to *some* provider that may also be rerendering for some reason, and thus, rerenders anything subscribed to it. You can rule out "mounting" renders with `useEffect(() => console.log('Mounted"), []);` to run an effect only once when the component mounts, if you see multiples then you know remounting is occurring. I think we'd need to see a bit more code to dig in on why you may be seeing more renders than expected.

Comment: Thanks Drew. So I added it and so that the component is remounted every time I visit a new page. Should I "unmount" it somehow? I should mention that I use React Navigation and I wrap each screen with a provider. I'll update that part in my original question and add any additional code you need to clarify.